# Wording : Is there a difference b/w rvalue and rvalue references?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue-reference

Say I have the following object

```
class foo
{
   foo() {..}                //Constructor 
   foo(const foo& f) {..}    //Copy Constructor - `f` is lvalue reference
   foo(foo&& g) {...}        //Move constructor 
};
```

Now I know that in the statement

```
 foo(const foo& f) {..}
```

f is an lvalue reference

Now my question is , in the statement

```
foo(foo&& g) {...}
```

I know `g` is an rvalue but I have heard and read here and there people refering to g as rvalue reference. my question is whats the difference between rvalue and rvalue reference or could they be used interchangeably?

Comment: You use `f` for both rvalue and lvalue in your example. This makes your post a bit confusing.

Comment: I changed the rvalue to `g`

Comment: @Rajeshwar: As T.C explains, `g` isn't an rvalue, although it is an rvalue reference.  The return value from `std::move` is both an rvalue and an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 2):

They are different.

In C++11 there are three categories of values: lvalues, xvalues ("eXpiring" values) and prvalues ("pure" rvalues). rvalues in C++11 consists of xvalues and prvalues.

A lvalue is an expression that identifies a non-temporary object or a non-member function. Of note, even if `x` is an rvalue reference, the expression `x` is an *lvalue*. In essence, if it's something with a name, it's an lvalue.

A xvalue is an expression that identifies an expiring object (that can be moved from). This includes such things as `std::move(x)` since it returns a rvalue reference, or `static_cast<X&&>(x)`

A prvalue identifies a temporary object or an value not associated with any object; this is the same as rvalues pre-C++11.

A rvalue reference binds only to rvalues. Thus, in

```
foo(foo&& f) {...}
```

f is a *rvalue reference* that has bound to a rvalue (either a xvalue or a prvalue), but the expression `f` itself is a *lvalue*. It's got a name, and you can take its address with `&f`. The point of rvalue references is that the object `f` is bound to is a rvalue and therefore can safely be moved from.